# Reading TCP Port of an IIS 7 website programmatically

Tags: iis, metabase

I have a C++ application that uses AHADMIN to interface with IIS 7. I know how to get a IAppHostElement object of my website, but no idea how to read properties (found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347565(v=vs.90).aspx, such as Object.ConfiguredObject.Site.Bindings) from there. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should bheck out Kanwal's post about AHADMIN: http://www.ksingla.net/tag/ahadmin/

In general you will want to use a combination of GetAdminSection (to get the section first), get_Collection (to get a pointer to the collection), get_Item (to get the item in the sites collection)  and GetElementByName (to get the bindings and repeat the collection/get_item) and GetPropertyByName for the value.

See also: http://www.ksingla.net/2009/04/implementing_iapphostpathmapper_in_c/
and http://forums.iis.net/t/1029458.aspx